# How to use Spark on Azure with a Data Factory in order to load and transform 2 files containing data

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-data-factory

I am very new to Spark as well as to the Data Factory resource in Azure.

I would like to use Spark on Azure to load and transform 2 files containing data.

Here is what I would like to achieve in more details:

1. Use a data factory on Azure and create a pipeline and use a Spark activity
2. Load 2 files containing data in JSONL format
3. Transform them by doing a "JOIN" on a given field that is existing in both
4. Output a new file containing the merged data

Anyone can help me achieve that?

As of now, I don't even understand how to load 2 files to work with in a Spark activity from a data factory pipeline...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two easiest ways to use Spark in an Azure Data Factory (ADF) pipeline are either via a Databricks cluster and the [Databricks activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-databricks-notebook) or use an Azure Synapse Analytics workspace, its built-in Spark notebooks and a Synapse pipeline (which is mostly ADF under the hood).

I was easily able to load a json lines file (using [this example](https://jsonlines.org/examples/)) in a Synapse notebook using the following python:

```
%%pyspark
df1=spark.read.load(['abfss://someLake@someStorage.dfs.core.windows.net/raw/json lines example.jsonl'],format='json')
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("main") 

df2=spark.read.load(['abfss://someLake@someStorage.dfs.core.windows.net/raw/json lines example 2.jsonl'],format='json')
df2.createOrReplaceTempView("ages")
```

You can now either join them in SQL, eg

```
%%sql
-- Join in SQL
SELECT m.name, a.age
FROM main m
    INNER JOIN ages a ON m.name = a.name
```

Or join them in Python:

```
df3 = df1.join(df2, on="name")
df3.show()
```

My results:

[image: My results]

I haven't tested this in Databricks but I imagine it's similar.  You might have to setup up some more permissions there as Synapse integration is slightly easier.

You could also look at Mapping Data Flows in ADF which uses Spark clusters under the hood and offers a low-code / GUI-based experience.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer! Can you tell me why choosing a Databricks activity in the pipeline over a HDInsight activity which says "Spark"?

Comment: I think Databricks and Synapse offer easier to deploy on-demand clusters and the notebook experience. I’d only use HDInsight if I need much more control over the Spark setup.

Answer (score 1):

There is literally a JOIN transformation built into ADF in the Data Flow activity that executes on Spark for you without needing to know anything about clusters or Spark programming :)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-join